# Match substring between delimiters instead of global delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching

I'm trying to retrieve the string between curly brackets in the code below. But instead of `string1`, `string2`etc...it gives `string1}{string2}{string3}{string4}{string5}{string6` in one string

```
var m   = "{string1}{string2}{string3}{string4}{string5}{string6}";
var res = /\{(.*)\}/g.exec(m);
alert(res.length); // returns 2
alert(res[1]);     // returns string1}{string2}{string3}{string4}{string5}{string6
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `?` for lazy match:

```
/{(.*?)}/g
```

Comment: thx for your reply! any idea why it still returns length equals 2 instead of returning the other substrings as well ?

Comment: @StephaneKouakou Because you need to run `exec` in loop to get all substrings. Read docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec.